# Black Screen after splash screen iOS, Swift, Xcode 6.4

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm using Xcode 6.4 my apps stimulator build successfully then splash screen then a black screen appear and it was stack. I tried different project same things appears black screen again but no errors.

Comment: show us your code please. (and maybe tell which hardware you are using)

Comment: I think it's Xcode 6.4, rather than iOS Swift 6.4

Answer (score 3):

Make sure one of the view controllers in your Storyboard is set as the initial view controller. You can set this property by selecting a view controller in the storyboard, selecting the Attributes Inspector, and then checking the box to the left of "Is Initial View Controller".